# Setting up web3 with Geth

Tags: ethereum, web3js, go-ethereum

I have been trying to set up my dapp, and have not found any resource that explains it thoroughly. I want to connect my application to ethereum using Geth and web3. So far, my index.js file looks like this:

```
var Web3 = require('web3')

 if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
   web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)
 } else {
   web3 = new Web3(new 
   Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'))
 }
```

And I type:

```
geth --testnet --rpc
```

to initiate the node in my command line. I have an npm script that runs geth and compiles index.js at the same time. Is there something I am missing? I also have another question. What is the correct way to import web3 using ES6 modules (import ... from ...)?

Comment: --rpccorsdomain "*" missed

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this command

```
geth --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain "*" console
```

`geth` has many options so you should read `geth` docs.

Comment: `--rpcaddr 0.0.0.0` is dangerous to use